# USART Configuration with Registers doesn't Work

Tags: c, usart, stm32f7

I am trying to implement a driver for USART for my board(F746G-Disco). For now, I implement:

```c
#include "UART_DRIVER.h"
#include "stm32f746xx.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal.h"
#include "stdint.h"

void uart_gpio_pin_init(void) {
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    
    // PA9 FOR USART1 TX AND PB7 FOR USART1 RX
    GPIOA->MODER |= (2U << 18); // ALTERNATE FUNCTION
    GPIOA->OTYPER |= (1U << 9);
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= (1U << 19);
    GPIOA->PUPDR |= (1U << 19);
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (7U << 4); // AF7

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIOB->MODER |= (2U << 6);
    GPIOB->OTYPER |= (1U << 7);
    GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= (1U << 17);
    GPIOB->PUPDR |= (1U << 17);
    GPIOB->AFR[0] |= (7U << 28); // AF7
}

void uart_init(void) {

    uart_gpio_pin_init();
    // disable USART
    USART1->CR1 = 0x00; // Disable Uart => UE=0
    USART1->CR1 &= (~(1U << 28) | ~(1 << 12)); // WORD LENGTH 8-BIT
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(1U << 15); // 16BIT OVERSAMPLING
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(1U << 10); // PARITY BIT DISABLE
    USART1->CR1 |= (1U << 3); // USART1 TRASNMITTER MODE
    USART1->CR1 |= (1U << 2); // USART1 RECEIVER MODE
    
    // 115200kpbs BAUD-RATE, SYSTEMCLOCK:168 MHz
    USART1->BRR = (0x5B2); 

    // ENABLE USART1
    USART1->CR1 = 0x01;
}


void uart_transmit_data(const char *data) {

    for (int var = 0; data[var] != '\0'; ++var) {
        USART1->TDR = (uint32_t)data[var];
        while((USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE) == 0);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the value of `USART1->CR1` does not change. In the manual, it is said that to have a writable bits, `Uart Enable(UE)` pin must be 0. I have already did that but still nothing change.
[reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00124865-stm32f75xxx-and-stm32f74xxx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[datasheet(look page 76 for alternate function mapping)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00124865-stm32f75xxx-and-stm32f74xxx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Solution Edit:
I have solved the problem. The problem is I didn't enable the clock for USART. Once `__HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();` macro is invoked in `uart_gpio_pin_init` function just before the register adjustments of USART, we get rid of the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the code that the USART clock wasn't enabled. Once `__HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();` macro is invoked in `uart_gpio_pin_init` function just before the register adjustments of USART, we get rid of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The part

```c
    // ENABLE USART1
    USART1->CR1 = 0x01;
```

will cancel the bits set in

```c
    USART1->CR1 |= (1U << 3); // USART1 TRASNMITTER MODE
    USART1->CR1 |= (1U << 2); // USART1 RECEIVER MODE
```

You may want to use OR instead of simple assignment:

```c
    // ENABLE USART1
    USART1->CR1 |= 0x01;
```

Comment: I solved the problem, but your suggestion clears something which were not clear in my mind. Thank you!

Comment: @akoluaciklinux if you solved it, please, write your own answer and describe in detail what the problem was and what you missed and how exactly you fixed it, and then select your own answer. Who knows, it may help someone some day. And it will also close the question.